# The constructor WindowEvent(WelcomeWindow, int) is undefined

Tags: java, constructor, jframe

Trying to implement a  close method for my Windowalthough java is giving a me a

"The constructor WindowEvent(WelcomeWindow, int) is undefined":ERROR

Line giving Error "WindowEvent winClosingEvent = **new WindowEvent(this,WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);**"

Can you please help me out

```
public class WelcomeWindow {

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    WelcomeWindow window = new WelcomeWindow();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public WelcomeWindow() {
        initialize();
    }


    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 248, 357);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{86, 0, 79, 0};
        gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(gridBagLayout);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Shop");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            }
        });
        GridBagConstraints gbc_btnNewButton = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_btnNewButton.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_btnNewButton.gridx = 1;
        gbc_btnNewButton.gridy = 2;
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton, gbc_btnNewButton);

        JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Manage Store");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_btnNewButton_1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_btnNewButton_1.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_btnNewButton_1.gridx = 1;
        gbc_btnNewButton_1.gridy = 3;
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_1, gbc_btnNewButton_1);

        JButton btnManageUsers = new JButton("Manage Users");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_btnManageUsers = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_btnManageUsers.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_btnManageUsers.gridx = 1;
        gbc_btnManageUsers.gridy = 5;
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnManageUsers, gbc_btnManageUsers);
    }
    public void close(){
        WindowEvent winClosingEvent = new WindowEvent(this,WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(winClosingEvent);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor that you are trying to use for "WindowEvent" is the following:

```
WindowEvent(Window source, int id)
```

So in order to used you "WelcomeWindow" class should be inheriting from

```
java.awt.Window
```

And since you are not overriding the Window constructors I'm guessing you didn't do it.

Futher reference here: [Java7 Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowEvent.html)

Comment: If it worked I would appreciate if you marked as an answer in the green checkmark at the left.

Comment: It worked but now i'm having trouble with the constructor, could you please elaborate on what i have to do to the Constructor.

Comment: Sorry @TYS I couldn't answer, I would recommend you to do another question so in which you can post your code and explain what is the purpose of what you are trying to do, otherwise read about inheritance and overriding methods.